# Understanding encoding schemes

Tags: encoding

I cannot understand some key elements of encoding:

1. Is ASCII only a character or it also has its encoding scheme algorithm ?
2. Does other windows code pages such as Latin1 have their own encoding algorithm ?
3. Are UTF7, 8, 16, 32 the only encoding algorithms ?
4. Does the UTF alghoritms are used only with the UNICODE set ?

Given the ASCII text: Hello World, if I want to convert it into Latin1 or BIG5, which encoding algorithms are being used in this process ?  More specifically, does Latin1/Big5 use their own encoding alghoritm or I have to use a UTF alghoritm ?

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean with 3. or why you specifically pick UTF-7 and 32…?

Comment: Hi, I updated my question. I was wondering if UTF alghoritms are the only ones which are being used to encode Unicode characters

Comment: #4. The U in UTF stands for Unicode. Algorithms can be applied anywhere you like but, please, let names have a declared or agreed upon context.

Answer (score 1):

1: Ascii is just an encoding — a really simple encoding. It's literally just the positive end of a signed byte (0...127) mapped to characters and control codes.

Refer to https://www.ascii.codes/ to see the full set and inspect the characters.

There are definitely encoding algorithms to convert ascii strings to and from strings in other encodings, but there is no compression/decompression algorithm required to write or read ascii strings like there is for utf8 or utf16, if that's what you're implying.

2: LATIN-1 is also not a compressed (usually called 'variable width') encoding, so there's no algorithm needed to get in and out of it.

See https://kb.iu.edu/d/aepu for a nice description of LATIN-1 conceptually and of each character in the set. Like a lot of encodings, its first 128 slots are just ascii. Like ascii, it's 1 byte in size, but it's an **unsigned** byte, so after the last ascii character (DEL/127), LATIN1 adds another 128 characters.

As with any conversion from one string encoding to another, there is an algorithm specifically tailored to that conversion.

3: Again, unicode encodings are just that — encodings. But they're all compressed except for utf32. So unless you're working with utf32 there is always a compression/decompression step required to write and read them.

Note: When working with utf32 strings there is one nonlinear oddity that has to be accounted for... combining characters. Technically that is yet another type of compression since they save space by not giving a codepoint to every possible combination of uncombined character and combining character. They "precombine" a few, but they would run out of slots very quickly if they did them all.

4: Yes. The compression/decompression algorithms for the compressed unicode encodings are just for those encodings. They would not work for any other encoding.

Think of it like zip/unzip. Unzipping anything other than a zipped file or folder would of course not work. That goes for things that are not compressed in the first place and also things that **are** compressed but using another compression algorithm (e.g.: rar).

I recently wrote the utf8 and utf16 compression/decompression code for a new cross-platform library being developed, and I can tell you quite confidently if you feed a Big5-encoded string into my method written specifically for decompressing utf8... not only would it not work, it might very well crash.

Re: your "Hello World" question... Refer to my answer to your second question about LATIN-1. No conversion is required to go from ascii to LATIN-1 because the first 128 characters (0...127) of LATIN-1 **are** ascii. If you're converting from LATIN-1 to ascii, the same is true for the lower half of LATIN-1, but if any of the characters beyond 127 are in the string, it would be what's called a "lossy"/partial conversion or an outright failure, depending on your tolerance level for lossiness. In your example, however, all of the characters in "Hello World" have the exact same values in both encodings, so it would convert perfectly, without loss, in either direction.

I know practically nothing about Big5, but regardless, don't use utf-x algos for other encodings. Each one of those is written very specifically for 1 particular encoding (or in the case of conversion: *pair* of encodings).

If you're curious about utf8/16 compression/decompression algorithms, the unicode website is where you should start *(watch out though. they don't use the compression/decompression metaphor in their documentation)*:

http://unicode.org

You probably won't need anything else.

... except maybe a decent codepoint lookup tool: https://www.unicode.codes/

You can roll your own code based on the unicode documentation, or use the official unicode library:

http://site.icu-project.org/home

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

In general, most encoding schemes like ASCII or Latin-1 are simply *big tables* mapping characters to specific *byte sequences*. There may or may not be some specific algorithm how the creators came up with those specific character⟷byte associations, but there's generally not much more to it than that.

One of the innovations of Unicode specifically is the indirection of assigning each character a unique number first and foremost, and worrying about how to encode that number into bytes secondarily. There are a number of encoding schemes for how to do this, from the [UCS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Coded_Character_Set) and [GB 18030](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GB_18030) encodings to the most commonly used UTF-8/UTF-16 encodings. Some are largely defunct by now like UCS-2. Each one has their pros and cons in terms of space tradeoffs, ease of processing and transportability (e.g. UTF-7 for safe transport over 7-bit system like email). [Unless otherwise noted](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode#Mapping_and_encodings), they can all encode the full set of current Unicode characters.

To convert from one encoding to another, you pretty much need to map bytes from one table to another. Meaning, if you look at the [EBCDIC table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBCDIC) and the [Windows 1250 table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1250), the characters `0xC1` and `0x41` respectively both seem to represent the same character "A", so when converting between the two encodings, you'd map those bytes as equivalent. Yes, that means there needs to be one such mapping between each possible encoding pair.

Since that is obviously rather laborious, modern converters virtually always go through Unicode as a middleman. This way each encoding only needs to be mapped to the Unicode table, and the conversion can be done with *encoding A → Unicode code point → encoding B*. In the end you just want to identify which characters look the same/mean the same, and change the byte representation accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

A character encoding is a mapping from a sequence of characters to a sequence of bytes (in the past there were also encodings to a sequence of bits - they are falling out of fashion). Usually this mapping is one-to-one but not necessarily onto. This means there may be byte sequences that don't correspond to a character sequence in this encoding.

The domain of the mapping defines which characters can be encoded.

Now to your questions:

1. ASCII is both, it defines 128 characters (some of them are control codes) and how they are mapped to the byte values 0 to 127.
2. Each encoding may define its own set of characters and how they are mapped to bytes
3. no, there are others as well ASCII, ISO-8859-1, ...
4. Unicode uses a two step mapping: first the characters are mapped to (relatively) small integers called "code points", then these integers are mapped to a byte sequence. The first part is the same for all UTF encodings, the second step differs. Unicode has the ambition to contain all characters. This means, most characters are in the "UNICODE set".

Comment: In point 4: the term is code units. Character sets are a set of codepoints: a mapping between a conceptual character and an integer. Character encodings have code units. They are a map between a codepoint and one or more code unit sequences. (And then there is serialization: a map between a code unit integer and a sequence of bytes with a given endianness.)

Answer (score 0):

Every character in the world has been assigned a unicode value [ numbered from 0 to ...]. It is actually an unique value. Now, it depends on an individual that how he wants to use that unicode value. He can even use it directly or can use some known encoding schemes like utf8, utf16 etc. Encoding schemes map that unicode value into some specific bit sequence [ can vary from 1 byte to 4 bytes or may be 8 in future **if we get to know about all the languages of universe/aliens/multiverse** ] so that it can be uniquely identified in the encoding scheme.

For example ASCII is an encoding scheme which only encodes 128 characters out of all characters. It uses one byte for every character which is equivalent to utf8 representation. GSM7 is one other format which uses 7 bit per character to encode 128 characters from unicode character list.

Utf8:
It uses 1 byte for characters whose unicode value is till 127.
Beyond this it has its own way of representing the unicode values.
Uses 2 byte for Cyrillic then 3 bytes for Hindi characters.

Utf16:
It uses 2 byte for characters whose unicode value is till 127.
and it also uses 2 byte for Cyrillic, Hindi characters.

All the utf encoding schemes fixes initial bits in specific pattern [ eg: 110|restbits] and rest bits [eg: initialbits|11001] takes the unicode value to make a unique representation.

Wikipedia on utf8, utf16, unicode will make it clear.
I coded an utf translator which converts incoming utf8 text across all languages into its equivalent utf16 text.